# icon not changing when button appended to header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, header, append

I'm appending a button to the header, and the only icon showing up is the plus, anything else is not working??

JavaScript

```
$('#addbuttons').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gears" data-theme="b">Edit</a>');
$('#addbuttons').append('<a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">New Event</a>');
```

HTML

```
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" id="hdr"></h1>
    <div class="ui-btn-right" id ="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `trigger`ing a `create` on your `data-role=page` after appending your buttons into `addbuttons` like this :

```
$("[data-role=page]").trigger("create");
```

Here's a demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/W7NcY/</kbd>

You could also try initiating `button` again like this :

```
$("[data-role=button]").button();
```

But you'll end up losing your rounded corners. I've noticed that adding `corners : true` inside button init hasnt helped.

Demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/W7NcY/4/</kbd>

Hope this helps.

Comment: the button icons in your demo still didn't change, the first one should be gears

Comment: @nshah you've made a typo in your question. It must be data-icon="gear", not data-icon=gear **s**

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the code there is a new button, it does not magically pick up on the changes.

```
$('#addbuttons')
    .append('<a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">New Event</a>')
    .find("a")
        .button()
        .button('refresh'); //<- probably not needed, put it here just in case.
```